# Is there any way I can hide the highlighted line in terminal?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I do my C codes in VS-Code. But every time I run a program, the highlighted line is always displayed.

[image]

For example, in the above picture, at the terminal the whole of output is always with the `cmd"c:\........ --interpreter=mi"`

Is there any way to hide this? I need to screenshot my projects with code for a presentation and that looks a bit unsightly.

Comment: Can you not just crop the relevant parts from the screenshot?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I could but I need both code and output in a single screenshot.

Comment: Have you considered using [Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) instead?

Comment: @wjandrea I personally do not recommend the Code Runner extension unless you want to do "scripting"... and even then, the C/C++ extension has a command to run the active file, so I'm not sure how much value it provides.

Answer (score 0):

You can do just by running "clear" command on the terminal to clear the previously runed cmd.

Comment: Thanks for replying. But `cls` clears all of the terminal including the output. I am looking for a way to just remove the `cmd /C "c:\users\....... --interpreter mi "` all the while just displaying the printf statements and stuff.

Answer (score 0):

```
clrscr();
```

OR

```
system(“cls”);
```

OR

```
system(“clear”);
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I do not need to clear the whole terminal. I just need to hide the command that is run in terminal. In this case, it is `cmd \C "c:\Users...... --interpreter mi "`.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but clearing the terminal before printing anything to it will achieve your desired output, right? In your case, you're trying to "suppress" the command that runs your actual code. However, you still have to type "./program.exe" into the terminal for the program to run. In short, the part where you are trying to clear the terminal is not the output of your code, so you cannot alter it.

Comment: I see. In short, it cannot be removed as the execution happens only after command, right? In that case, is there any way I can shorten the path. For example, if I do the same program in Python, the command is a single line which looks neater. If no, thanks for clarifying above doubt.

Comment: Correct. In Python it would be as short as; `D:\Programs\project-path> python Practical 1a.python`. You can also "disable" path in the terminal, see; https://superuser.com/questions/315354/how-do-i-hide-the-path-in-command-line-prompt-on-windows . Also, you can try running your program in default mode rather than VSCode's debugger mode. Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Try the alternative approach, open a terminal run your cmd and then open new terminal in vs code it allows you to run your cmd in the background (when you run a cmd using 1st terminal) and this is a new terminal use it as you need now